# Show pdf in the browser in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, pdf

I have a tab on my page, when i click on this tab, i need to show a pdf file on page(browser).
For this i am writing function on control like this

```
public ActionResult PricedPdf(string projID,string fileName)
{
    byte[] bArr = new byte[] { };
    bArr = getdata();    
    return File(bArr, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Pdf, fileName+".pdf");
}
```

Now my problem is when i render this, page only show some unreadable data not pdf.

May be the problem is due to jquery tab, I am using Jquery tab

I used this in place of File, but still showing same problem

```
public ActionResult PricedPdf(string projID, string fileName)
{
    byte[] bArr = new byte[] { };
    bArr = getdata();
    Response.AddHeader("Content-disposition", "inline; filename=\"" + fileName + "\"");
    Response.ContentType = "application/" + System.IO.Path.GetExtension(fileName).Replace(".", "");    
    Response.BinaryWrite(bArr);
    Response.Flush();
}
```

Comment: That's probably because the `getdata` function you are using doesn't generate a valid PDF.

Comment: i am geting pdf in byte format correct, is there problem in pass byte data to File()

Comment: Are you trying to embed this inside a page or link to it? You can't embed PDFs inside a page like this.

Comment: i am using Jquery tabs, in jquery tab system it create a div and all return type bind in taht div

Comment: Please guide me is there any other way to do this? is there any way i can show pdf inside user control

Comment: @Pankaj, this won't work with AJAX calls. Please see my answer.

Comment: You should not allocate new array before assign a variable, i.e.: `byte[] bArr = getdate();` and that's all

Answer (score 0):

How are you calling this `PricedPdf` action? If you are calling it with AJAX then forget about it. You cannot return PDF from an AJAX call or more precisely you can but there's not much you can do with it. So create a normal html link pointing to this action:

```
<%= Html.ActionLink("show pdf", "PricedPdf") %>
```

Once you click on the resulting anchor the browser will be **redirected** to a page that will open the resulting PDF using the appropriate plugin installed on your system (provided there's any). If you don't want opening the PDF in the current browser window you could add the `target="_blank"` attribute to the anchor.

Finally if you want to open the PDF only inside some portion of the page you could [embed it](http://blog.flashcolony.com/?p=244) into the markup.

So basically you would have a controller action that will return a partial HTML containing the PDF inclusion:

```
public ActionResult SomePartial()
{
    return PartialView();
}
```

And the partial might look like this:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl" %>
<object type="application/pdf" data="<%= Url.Action("PricedPdf") %>" width="500" height="650">
    Click <%= Html.ActionLink("here", "PricedPdf") %> to view the file
</object>
```

And in you would use this action in your AJAX call.